Proof of address and funds when visiting Singapore
I am a New Zealand passport holder with Indian origin.
I have planned a trip to India and on my way to India I want to visit Singapore staying at my sisters home a to  Singapore. When I googled regarding visiting Singapore, I came to know that either I should show sufficient cash in hand at the entry point or give the address of my sister where I have planned to stay. I can give my sisters address but I want to know whether I have to submit a letter (much in advance) from my sister saying that she is ready to accommodate me.
Can anybody answer.
Bhavani

As a citizen of New Zealand, you can stay in Singapore for 30 days without a visa. You are also entitled to use the Automated Clearance gates, which means that you can in all likelihood enter Singapore without ever talking to a human, just remember to fill out your Arrival Card in advance!
In the unlikely event that you are quizzed on entry, having an address and contact details (phone number) for your sister will be sufficient. You need to prove you have enough funds for your stay, but a credit card etc is sufficient, you do not need to bring cash.  It would not hurt to bring a printout of your onward flight from Singapore, which you can use to demonstrate that you will be leaving before the 30 days is up.

The greatest issue is unfortunately convincing gate agents. :)

valuable information

@BalachandranAlwar If this answered your question, please accept it by clicking the ✔️ mark!

I had almost the same case. Indian citizen, staying at a relative's place while visiting Singapore. I just carried a print out with the following details.
Stay in Singapore
Name: <Name>
Relation: Uncle
Address: <Address>
Contact Details: <Phone>
Arrival Date:
Departure Date:

Apparently, carrying a printed documentation checks their (Airline gate agents) boxes and they don't ask further.
When arriving in Singapore, you just have to go through automated gates, as you must have already submitted your stay details in digital arrival form.

As an Indian citizen who generally needs a visa for Singapore, you will be subjected to more scrutiny than OP, who is a visa-free NZ citizen.

useful information
